# Save and restore variable

Tags: spacemacs, hooks, minor-mode, variables

I am working on Spacemacs which gives you the ability toggle between Emacs "holy-mode" and Vim "evil-mode". However the `evil-escape` minor mode is still enabled. I am trying to find some way to disable `evil-escape` in the `holy-mode` setup function and then restore its previous state (enabled/disabled) in `holy-mode`'s teardown function. I tried this but it didn't work.

```
  ;; setup
  (setq evil-escape-mode-set (symbol-value 'evil-escape-mode))
  (evil-escape-mode -1)

  ;; teardown
  (when (evil-escape-mode-set)
     (evil-escape-mode))
```

but the teardown doesn't seem to work. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: No need to use `symbol-value` or even define a variable. Every properly defined mode defined a variable with the same name you can use for this.

Comment: But when I have to save that variable `evil-escape-mode` in order to restore it correct?

Comment: No, it's set to `nil` or `t` by the mode.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear to me just what you are trying to do.

But it looks like you are setting a *variable* and then expecting it to be used as a *function*.

Emacs Lisp is a "Lisp 2", which means that you can have a variable and a function with the same name, and they are totally unrelated, by default. It also means that if you want to invoke a function-valued variable you need to use something like `funcall` or `apply`, not just have that symbol as the car of a list that is evaluated.

I think all you really want to do is this:

```
(when evil-escape-mode-set ...
```

instead of this:

```
(when (evil-escape-mode-set) ...
```